# Can I retrieve Whatsapp voicenotes which have been deleted while recording?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

If I record a voicenote on Whatsapp and there is an interruption while doing so (incoming call, calendar notification), the recording is immediately aborted by Whatsapp.  A little dustbin pops up in the bottom right corner and I cannot stop the recording from being deleted.  Is that "piece" of recording available somewhere or was it never saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dustbin animation is shown the voice note probably is deleted.

Or you can check all the saved voice notes on the SD card. 
The path is 
`Whatsapp/Media/Whatsapp Voice`